# Can I delete/clear all my comments?

Tags: support

Can I Clear/delete all comments which is posted by me? I know I filter It from [Activity>Comments Tab](https://askubuntu.com/users/256099/pandya?tab=activity&sort=comments) But It has about 9 pages. so it is difficult to delete one-by-one.

So, How to **delete all comments**? **Is it possible (permitted)**?

Comment: I want to manually clear all my comments every-month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think deleting all your comments is a good idea. Manually or otherwise.

While comments in general are considered to be transient (and less important than answers),  they often form part of a conversation that gives context to a post. If you blanket-delete your half of that conversation, you're removing part of that context and making the comments less useful.

More than anything I don't see what *you* get from deleting content. It's not as if it's counted against you.

To be clear, *some* comments become obsolete, redundant... But you find those by checking up on old comments, and reading the replies... Not going on a blind deletion spree.